# EXEC %%System().FireTrigger

Tags: sql-server

I was just wondering what is this?

```
EXEC %%System().FireTrigger(ID = 225, ID = 102, ID = 0, ID = 0, Value = @server,
ID = -1, ID = 0, ID = 0, Value = NULL, 
ID = 7, Value = @server, Value = @srvproduct2, Value = @provider, Value = @datasrc, Value = @location, Value = NULL, Value = @catalog)
```

I have been trying to look for it in mssql but I cant find it, what does it mean? I know `EXEC` is used to execute stored procedure, but what is `%%System()?`

and what is `FireTrigger`? is it an embedded command in the system? external dll? been trying to Google it but it seems to be vague at the moment.

Comment: [It's all undocumented](https://sqlblog.org/2009/08/22/peeking-under-the-hood-what-bits-have-changed-in-sql-server-2008-r2). As for what this might achieve, `@srvproduct2` makes me think of linked servers.

Comment: Yes, what is this?  Where did you get it from and why do you think that it is valid SQL and should do something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an internal mechanism that is sometimes exposed but you can't call it yourself and it is undocumented.

Comment: it is a part of code in a stored procedure  being executed, somehow there is an error in it, due to the fact that we are trying to reverse engineer it and make it work, and we are getting error because of it. the sp is called 

    sp_addlinkedserver

Comment: Thank you for the answer guys, found out the problem was not here. Accepted the answer.