# Two Percent Signs in EXEC Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2014, the master database contains a system stored procedure called sp_rename. I was interested to know how it works, so I've been taking a look at it.

On line 190, there is an EXEC statement that contains two percent signs:

```
EXEC %%ScalarType(MultiName = @SchemaAndTypeName).LockMatchID(ID = 
@xusertype, Exclusive = 1)
```

What does the %% mean? I've searched around online, but haven't found anything that even remotely mentions it.

Comment: IIRC these designate special built-in system/compiler functions that don't actually exist in the released product (or else, are not accessible).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So if I change nothing, but execute the code to "alter" the procedure, the percent signs give syntax errors. That's because I'm just a normal user that SQL Server thinks is trying to access a system function which is not accessible to users. I think that makes sense. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Right.  I'm not even sure it's shipped with SQL Server.  My understanding is that not all of the system SQL code we see in scripts is "real".  Some of it is placeholder for underlying internal code of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456164/exec-system-firetrigger), it's an undocumented component of SQL Server. Basically, these are system commands that a typical user is not supposed to reference. Since you're looking at the components of a stored procedure, you'll see scripts that are normally inaccessible to a normal user.

Since the `%%` is (intentionally) undocumented it's difficult to determine exactly how the system is using it, but one can reasonably assume it's an indicator of system-only commands.